# Graphics driver for HP Pavilion Slimline - s5710f Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, graphics

After installing Ubuntu 12.04, I noticed that no graphics driver has been recognized. I know that this PC is a HP Pavilion Slimline s5710f and it has an integrated graphics card, which I believe is an Radeon 3000.

I did search around and found this: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=Legacy2&os=Linux%20x86_64

I'm just not sure what to install.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

try this out and see what you get. people recommend different locations for storing the .run file, some say your "home" folder or "/etc/opt/"

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingRunPackage